# uploading file to dropbox using V2 in custom PHP

Tags: php, api, dropbox-api

I have written code for file uploading and it is working fine on one server but not on local machine. Following is code:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1);

$api_url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload'; //dropbox api url

$token = 'fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: ' .
    json_encode(
            array(
                "path" => '/' . basename('image/1st.jpg'),
                "mode" => "add",
                "autorename" => true,
                "mute" => false
            )
    ),
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
);

$ch = curl_init($api_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$path = 'images/1st.jpg';

$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
$filesize = filesize($path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>response === "; print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>http_code === "; print_r($http_code); echo "</pre>";


?>
```

When i run this code on local, i got following output:

```
response === 
http_code === 0
```

On test server, it produce following output:

```
{"name": "1st.jpg", "path_lower": "/1st.jpg", "path_display": "/1st.jpg", "id": "id:UDbOKdE2bKXXXXXXECg", "client_modified": "2017-10-10T10:05:11Z", "server_modified": "2017-10-10T10:05:11Z", "rev": "4075316e33a", "size": 143578, "content_hash": "f30041XXXXXXXXXXX35ee3cXXXXXXe649afe8d"}
200
```

what can be possible reason for this issue?

Comment: What does curl_error($ch); shows ?

Comment: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following steps resolved issue for me:

1) Download the latest cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

2) Add the following line to php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable SSL veryfy host:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

Or more correct way is:

Download a file with the updated list of certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Move the downloaded cacert.pem file to some safe location in your system

Update your php.ini file and configure the path to that file:

```
; Linux and macOS systems
curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"

; Windows systems
curl.cainfo = "C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
```

Comment: i think this is not an answer so should be posted as comment instead of question.